# Error when calling a method in a setInterval

Tags: javascript, setinterval, undefined-function

I am having trouble calling methods in a setInterval... Here is a snippet of my code...

```
var example = function(){

    this.animate = function(){
        console.log("Animate.");
    }

    this.updateTimer = function(){ // This is being called...
        this.timer = setInterval(function(){
            this.animate(); // A "Undefined Is Not A Function" error is being thrown here.
        }, 1);
    }

}
```

Comment: This question has been asked and answered probably half a dozen times. You need to read up on exactly what `this` means and where it comes from. Did you try debugging this? Simply putting a breakpoint on the line in question and examining the value of `this` would have given you all the clues you needed.

Comment: Also see Mike West's [Scope in JavaScript](http://www.digital-web.com/articles/scope_in_javascript/). Mike is a very good writer, and the article is very well written.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130241/pass-correct-this-context-to-settimeout-callback, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101668/how-to-use-settimeout-to-invoke-object-itself, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21429255/why-is-an-anonymous-function-required-to-preserve-this-using-settimeout, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21370768/setinterval-callback-with-context, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11931612/about-settimeout-interval-context/11931662#11931662, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308790/javascript-context-problem-using-setinterval-with-prototype, and two more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### USE BIND (as @torazaburo said)

**maybe best-practice**

http://jsfiddle.net/rnrlabs/Lnmex1y7/

```
var example = function(){
    this.animate = function(){
        console.log("Animate.");
    }    
    this.updateTimer = function() { // This is being called...
        this.timer = setInterval(this.animate.bind(this), 1);
    }
}
```

### OR.. USE A CLOSURE

http://jsfiddle.net/rnrlabs/zk6hdnf2/

```
var example = function(){

    var self = this; // this creates a closure

    this.animate = function(){
        console.log("Animate.");
    }

    this.updateTimer = function(){ 
        this.timer = setInterval(function(){
            // 'this' here means window element.
            self.animate(); 
        }, 1);
    }

}
```

Comment: Or, if you prefer, `setInterval(this.animate.bind(this), 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

you cant not use `this` in setInterval
use this code

edite `this.animate()` to `example.animate()`

use this code

```
var example = function(){

    this.animate = function(){
        console.log("Animate.");
    }

    this.updateTimer = function(){ // This is being called...
        this.timer = setInterval(function(){
            example.animate(); // A "Undefined Is Not A Function" error is being thrown here.
        }, 1);
    }

}
```